# Is there a way to make icon from difference source have the same size?

Tags: html, css

I have a three container.Each container have Icon,Heading and Paragraph.But I use the icon from difference source.Fist icon(Branding) is from google and other remaining icon(Desktop,Mobile) is from fontawesome.The problem is first icon is not have equal size with the 2 remaining icon and this make the heading and paragraph of Branding item not display in the same line with heading and paragraph of the remaing item.I try to fix it by put first icon in the container and adjust it's position but it's not working.Is there a way to make all of icon have the same size?

Picture
[image]
First icon in container

```
<div class="i-container">
   <i class="material-icons" id="Branding">menu_book</i>
</div>
```

```css
.work-container{
    width:1200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
}

.box{
    border:1px solid #c59a6d;
    height:430px;
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.box i{
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.i-container{
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
   
}
.i-container i{
    font-size: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -28px;
}
/*
.box i.material-icons{
    color:blue;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}*/
.box h2{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
}


.box p{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 300px;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<head>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"             rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a022b2977b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="work-container">
                <div class ="box">
                    <div class="i-container">
                        <i class="material-icons" id="Branding">menu_book</i>
                    </div>   
                        <h2>BRANDING</h2>
                        <p>
                        Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus 
                        qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
                        </p>
                
                </div>
                <div class ="box">
                    
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-desktop" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>
                  
                        <h2>DESKTOP</h2>
                    <p>
                    Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus 
                    qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class ="box">
                    
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>
                    <h2>MOBILE</h2>
                    <p>
                    Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus 
                    qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get things aligned is to put them into a grid.

In this case each box can be a single column grid with three rows, the first with the icon, the second with the heading and the third with the p element.

Removing all the use of px units for positioning (margins) and instead letting the system work things out also makes the whole more responsive.

An addition here has been to remove the fixed with of the whole thing (but of course put it back if it's essential to your use case!) and to make the overall flexed with a gap so it's more responsive.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a022b2977b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .work-container {
      width: 100vw;
      border: 1px solid green;
      display: flex;
      gap: 2vw;
    }
    
    .box {
      border: 1px solid #c59a6d;
      height: 430px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 5fr;
    }
    
    .box>* {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .box>p {
      align-items: start;
      justify-content: left;
    }
    
    .box i {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .i-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .i-container i {
      font-size: 120px;
    }
    
    .box h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 36px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .box p {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 36px;
      font-weight: 400;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    
    i.fa-solid,
    .i-container {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="work-container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="i-container">
        <i class="material-icons" id="Branding">menu_book</i>
      </div>
      <h2>BRANDING</h2>
      <p>
        Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="box">

      <i class="fa-solid fa-desktop" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>

      <h2>DESKTOP</h2>
      <p>
        Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">

      <i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>
      <h2>MOBILE</h2>
      <p>
        Accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You may want to change the proportions of the grid (currently 3fr, 1fr, 5fr) to give the icon or text more or less space.